# Performing the Interaction with ARKit and the Multipeer connectivity I cannot see the objects placed with one device on the second one

Tags: ios, arkit, multipeer-connectivity, anchorpoint

I am using the [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality) provided by apple for interacting with 3D objects (from Google Poly) and I am trying to incorporate the Multipeer connectivity framework in this project. I am also trying to use this other [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_multiuser_ar_experience) given from Apple.

When I incorporated the multipeer code into the arkit interaction (merged these two codes), I managed to connect two nearby devices and send the world map between them. But, although it says that I have sent the world map from device1 to device2, the problem is that I can't see the objects in device2. I guess I am making some mistake in creating the anchor for the object (so that's why the objects are invisible) but I can't figure out why. Can someone please try to explain where I might be wrong?